# powershell keep specific lines in csv

Tags: csv, powershell

I have a csv file that looks like the following. I need to lose the header and footer and keep just the data. I could do it with a line count, however the header and footer will never be the same. And the file length will constantly change. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Sample CSV:

```
,Table 1-4,,,,,,,,,,,
,Some BS,,,,,,,,,,,
,More crap that doesn't matter,,,,,,,,,,,
,"Blah Blah Inc. ",,,,,,,,,,,
,"Year 2014, Quarter 1",,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,
,ID,First Name,Last Name,Sex1,Birth date,Flag,Some Number ,Individual Thing ,,,,
,456435634A,ALBERT ,SMITH ,1 ,07/24/1964 ,0 ,742109842 ,18018,,,,
,745675674A,ALBERT ,SMITH ,1 ,07/24/1964 ,0 ,742109842 ,17808,,,,
,234523455A,CARLTON ,JONES ,1 ,10/04/1953 ,0 ,742109842 ,15088,,,,
,567567567D,ANITA ,COX ,2 ,10/09/1967 ,0 ,742109842 ,19321,,,,
,6578678885A,SUSAN ,WOOD ,2 ,07/23/1934 ,0 ,742109842 ,12758,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,
,Notes:,,,,,,,,,,,
,"Notes the I dont care about.",,,,,,,,,,,
,See note regarding Definition of PCS in the Parameters Worksheet.,,,,,,,,,,,
,"Some more notes.",,,,,,,,,,,
,"Yet even more.",,,,,,,,,,,
,Wow even more and no quotes this time.,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,
,"Disclaimer blah blah blah.",,,,,,,,,,,
```

Comment: Wouldn't even call it a CSV-file. It's a messy document.. You have random text, 5+ empty columns etc.  clean up your data

Comment: Well, it's what was given to me. They powers that be call it a csv file and it's what I have to work with. The goal is to clean up this file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this could work

```
@'
,Table 1-4,,,,,,,,,,,
,Some BS,,,,,,,,,,,
,More crap that doesn't matter,,,,,,,,,,,
,"Blah Blah Inc. ",,,,,,,,,,,
,"Year 2014, Quarter 1",,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,
,ID,First Name,Last Name,Sex1,Birth date,Flag,Some Number ,Individual Thing ,,,,
,456435634A,ALBERT ,SMITH ,1 ,07/24/1964 ,0 ,742109842 ,18018,,,,
,745675674A,ALBERT ,SMITH ,1 ,07/24/1964 ,0 ,742109842 ,17808,,,,
,234523455A,CARLTON ,JONES ,1 ,10/04/1953 ,0 ,742109842 ,15088,,,,
,567567567D,ANITA ,COX ,2 ,10/09/1967 ,0 ,742109842 ,19321,,,,
,6578678885A,SUSAN ,WOOD ,2 ,07/23/1934 ,0 ,742109842 ,12758,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,
,Notes:,,,,,,,,,,,
,"Notes the I dont care about.",,,,,,,,,,,
,See note regarding Definition of PCS in the Parameters Worksheet.,,,,,,,,,,,
,"Some more notes.",,,,,,,,,,,
,"Yet even more.",,,,,,,,,,,
,Wow even more and no quotes this time.,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,
,"Disclaimer blah blah blah.",,,,,,,,,,,
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header h1, ID, FirstName, LastName, Sex1, BirthDate, Flag, SomeNumber, IndividualThing, h10, h11, h12 |
    Where-Object id -Match '^\d+\w$' |
    Select-Object ID, FirstName, LastName, Sex1, BirthDate, Flag, SomeNumber, IndividualThing |
    Export-Csv c:\temp\justthedata.csv -NoTypeInformation

start C:\temp\justthedata.csv
```

if you're using a file, replace this and everything before it

```
... | ConvertFrom-Csv
```

with this

```
import-csv 'C:\temp\file.csv'
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked great.